# Creating a UEFI bootable Win7 USB stick

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

I'm using winsb to create a bootable usb stick. In terminal I enter this command:

```
    winusb --install'/home/obaid/Downloads/Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 (64 Bit)/Windows.iso' /dev/sdb
```

It returns an error:

```
    mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/winusb_iso_1423415599_8150’: Permission denied
    Error occured !
    Syncing...
    Cleaning...
    Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1423415599_8150'...
    umount: /media/winusb_iso_1423415599_8150 is not mounted (according to mtab)
    Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1423415599_8150'...
    umount: /media/winusb_target_1423415599_8150 is not mounted (according to mtab)
```

I'm new to ubuntu and have no idea how to fix this, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from reading your first error message (*"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/winusb_iso_1423415599_8150’: Permission denied"*) it looks like you need more permission to create directories in `/media'.

If you appended `sudo` to the start of your command, it would run `winusb` as root and give it permission to create (and delete) just about everything:

```
sudo winusb --install'/home/obaid/Downloads/Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 (64 Bit)/Windows.iso' /dev/sdb
```

`sudo` should be given some thought before being used, it can be quite dangerous. I'm unfamiliar with `winusb`, not even sure if it's in a default repository or from a random webpage download, so I can't judge whether or not it's a good idea to give it root access...